# decrypting a value read from disk fails with EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt message

Tags: openssl

Am getting this error "error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt".  when I encrypt a buffer and persist it to writing to disk and trying to read the value from disk by decrypting it.  I made sure the key, IV are same in both cases.  Tried disabling or enabling padding during encryption and decryption. But still getting same error.

The thing is when I try to decrypt the value before writing to extended attributes, the decryption was a success.

Am using AES256 symmetric cipher related EVP functions.

What other things that I need to verify here?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the problem must lie in writing and reading extended attributes, which would probably be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com. Have you done a byte-by-byte comparison of the ciphertext before and after writing/reading the extended attribute?